# Are inline attribute validators allowed?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation, asp.net-web-api, modelstate

When creating a webApi controller, where the only parameter passed is a string, can I apply a validator attribute for 'Required', or 'String Length'?

This does not seem to work for me...

**Example of controller action:**

```
[HttpPost]
[ActionName("GetInventoryDetails")]
public HttpResponseMessage GetInventoryDetails([FromBody][Required][StringLength(20)]string serialNumber)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid == true)
    {            
        var response = Request.CreateResponse(statusCode: HttpStatusCode.OK, value: string.Empty, mediaType: Request.Content.Headers.ContentType);
        return response;
    }
    else
    {
        var response = Request.CreateResponse(statusCode: HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        return response;
    }
}
```

when I pass in a string longer than 20 characters ModelState.IsValid is true.  Also, if I pass no parameter ModelState.IsValid is also true.  In both cases I was expecting `ModelState.IsValid` to be false.

BTW - if instead I construct a controller action to accept an object instead of a string, and if I place attribute validators on properties of the class then validation works as expected, and `ModelState.IsValid` shows false.  It is only when trying to use attribute validators inline as in my example above where the `ModelState.IsValid` is showing an unexpected result.

Comment: I think your last para pretty much answers your question, no?

Comment: Well, not sure I answered my own question.  Perhaps I am not doing it correctly.  Perhaps it works if done a different way...

Comment: You can read here on how you can implement that yourself: https://blog.markvincze.com/how-to-validate-action-parameters-with-dataannotation-attributes/

Comment: @Evk - unfortunately my company blocks the site you recommend... :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You answered your own question in that it does NOT work.
However the attribute usage is defined as

`[AttributeUsageAttribute(AttributeTargets.Property | AttributeTargets.Field | AttributeTargets.Parameter, AllowMultiple = false)]`

Since Parameter is allowed it would seem like it could work but obviously not.
Now you could create your own action attribute that you could then enforce the validation from.

Comment: For giggles, I created a custom validation attribute and bound it to my action parameter.  It never gets called.  I guess the simple answer is webApi does not support validation attributes when the input is a string and not a class where properties can be decorated with validator attributes.  Weird - I would have thought the most basic use of a rest service would include validation capabilities.  Having said that, I believe I will box the parameter into a class and add validation there.  This means the payload size will increase and marshaling required to copy the value out of the input class.

Comment: Going the class way is definitely the more MVC way of handling it. Anything else is more work then is worthwhile.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the issue is in your HTTP request. The request needs to be formatted slightly differently if you're accepting an object or a single string parameter.

If you accept an object (the way you said works) then the body of your request would be a JSON object with a property called `serialNumber`:

```
{ serialNumber: "serial1234" }
```

However, if you accept only a single string parameter, then [according to the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api#using-frombody), the body of your request should be "a raw JSON string (not a JSON object)". So it should look something like this:

```
"serial1234"
```

The quotes are only needed if the Content-Type on your request is "application/json". If you send it as "text/plain", then you probably don't need the quotes.

Comment: standard JSON object notation did not work at all.  only a basic string (as in your second example) actually passes data into the controller action...